# Thymeleaf swallows option tags inside datalist

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf, datalist

I have the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head></head>

<body>

<input type = "text" name="city" id="city-selector" list="available-cities" autofocus/>
    <datalist  id="available-cities">
        <option value="1">Madrid</option>
        <option value="2">Barcelona</option>
        <option value="3">Sevilla</option>
        <option value="4">Valencia</option>

    </datalist>

</body>

</html>
```

When I add this as static content in my Spring Boot application, it works and I am able to use the datalist feature. However, if I add this file as a Thymeleaf template and use a Spring controller to route the request to the template, the datalist gets rendered as the following:

```
<datalist id="available-cities"> Madrid Barcelona Sevilla Valencia </datalist>
```

The option tags dissappear and all their values are concatenated. The datalist no longer works, since there are no option tags.

Is this a Thymeleaf bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems this issue is related to the use of the LEGACYHTML5 mode of Thymeleaf, as explained [here](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/338).

The workaround is to [use Thymeleaf 3](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-thymeleaf-3) to avoid using nekohtml or, if that is not an option, change to HTML5 mode by including the following line in application.properties:

```
spring.thymeleaf.mode: HTML
```

Answer (score 1):

Thymeleaf 3 solved this issue. By default spring boot uses thymeleaf 2. The following steps should do the job:

In your application.properties add:

```
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

and in your pom.xml add:

```
<properties>
    <thymeleaf.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
    <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.1.1</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-docs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using LEGACYHTML5, you can change your list by:

```
<datalist  id="available-cities">
 <select>
    <option value="1">Madrid</option>
    <option value="2">Barcelona</option>
    <option value="3">Sevilla</option>
    <option value="4">Valencia</option>
 </select>
</datalist>
```